# Why $dateToString (aggregation) converted the date with 1 day less?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this document

```
{
  'datetime_expiration': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
  'id_profile': 1
}
```

When I convert the field `datetime_expiration` to string

```
{
'$project': {
  'datetime_expiration': {
      '$dateToString': {
        'date': '$datetime_expiration',
        'format': '%Y-%m-%d',
        'timezone': 'America/Sao_Paulo',
        'onNull': null
      }
   }
 }
}
```

mongo subtracts one day. Result:

```
{
  'datetime_expiration': '2019-12-31'
  'id_profile': 1
}
```

As you can see, before the `'$project'` we had `2020-01-01`, but after we got `2019-12-31`.
Why is this happening? I'm in Brazil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because all dates are written in UTC by default - check here :: [MongoDB-Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/), For `$dateToString` when you pass a timezone like this `'timezone': 'America/Sao_Paulo'` then it would remove the offset from the UTC date-time passed in & then give you the date. As your timezone is `UTC-3` then it would deduct 3 hours from `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00` which results as `2019-12-31T21:00:00.000+00:00`, So the date will be `'2019-12-31'` - In case if you need date as is then do not specify timezone.

From documentation on timezone option of `$dateToString` :

> timezone is Optional. The timezone of the operation result.  must be
>   a valid expression that resolves to a string formatted as either an
>   Olson Timezone Identifier or a UTC Offset. If no timezone is provided,
>   the result is displayed in UTC.

**Ref:** [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)